# Filter gcloud machine types by CPU architecture

Tags: ruby, google-compute-engine, gcloud

I would like to get a list of available machine types filtered by CPU architecture using Ruby API [Google::Apis::ComputeV1::ComputeService](https://googleapis.dev/ruby/google-api-client/latest/Google/Apis/ComputeV1/ComputeService.html#list_machine_types-instance_method).

Currently there is only the Tau T2A series for ARM, but I don't want to filter machines by name to be able to use the others when they become available.

Filtering by "Ampere Altra" cpuPlatform returns an empty list, but there are such available machines.

```rb
@service.fetch_all do |token|
  @service.list_machine_types(@gcp_config['project'], @gcp_config['zone'], page_token: token, filter: 'cpuPlatform = "Ampere Altra"')
end
```

Comment: If you're using [`machineTypes:list`](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/machineTypes/list) even though the example filter includes `cpuPlatform`, this property does **not** appear to be part of the request (or response). You can confirm this using "Try this method" on that page or by `gcloud compute machine-types list --project=${PROJECT} --zones=${ZONE} --format=yaml --limit=5`

Comment: I have also noticed that there is no such field in the response, but the authors of the documentation use such a misleading example. This is quite strange.